# How do I add a line custom component on the seekbar using videoJS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, video.js

I just tried to represent watched buffer. like below picture.

but there are some errors due to the css.

so i was googling.

there must be a way to add a custome component like a bar on the ControlBar.

so can you give me an advise for adding component?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zjBd.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBvZf.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.